# Are there still events in the books that are yet to happen on the show?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Considering the books until *A Dance with Dragons* and the show until season 6 are there any major events that the show didn't cover yet? Before seeing the finale I was thinking

> Sam didn't reach Oldtown yet and Kevan and Pycelle are still alive

But those were taken care of in the finale although in a different way.

Plotlines that are in the books that probably won't make it in the show I like to exclude like Aegon, Lady Stoneheart and Victarion.

I'm looking for events like characters' deaths, certain characters reaching certain places and other things that most likely end up in the show but was not in season 6.

Comment: This is really subjective and broad. Honestly the answer is going to be "maybe, we don't know"

Comment: Seems like a fair question to me, if the OP is asking if there are any events in the 5 *currently published* books that haven't been in the show *so far.*

Comment: @JoeL. The issue is this line. "Most likely end up in the show". How do we define what will or will not? Especially when the OP arbitrarily excludes certain plot lines?

Comment: Alot, as many of them are removed and even altered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only story line that is still a bit behind from what we see in the books is Sam's.

In the books he has been in Old Town for a bit (maybe a month or so). We have not been shown some of the knowledge he begins to learn there.

The plots in the North, South, East, West, Kings Landing, Bravos, and Meeren have all advanced farther than the books.

---

It is worth pointing out that the show has arrived at many plot conclusions in a different way than the books have. Going forward I think it is going to be difficult to compare the books the show.

This is the [quote](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/It-Official-Game-Thrones-Spoil-Ending-George-R-R-Martin-Books-70847.html) from Dave Benioff on the issue:

> Luckily, we’ve been talking about this with George [R.R. Martin] for a long time... and we know where things are heading. So, we’ll eventually meet up at pretty much the same place where George is going. There might be a few deviations along the route, but we’re heading towards the same destination

George himself had [this to say](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/How-George-R-R-Martin-Feels-About-Game-Thrones-Ending-His-Books-80537.html) around the end of Season 5:

> There was a period where I was worried about that. Then I said, to hell with that. Worrying about it isn’t going to change it one way or another. I still sit down at the typewriter, and I have to write the next scene and the next sentence … I’m just going to tell my story, and they’re telling their story and adapting my books, and we shall see.

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole plot line which wasn't even mentioned in the TV series.

Huge spoiler if you didn't read the books, especially for *A Dance with Dragons*:

> Someone is claiming to be Aegon Targaryen, which was assumed to be murdered during the Sack of King's Landing at the end of Robert's rebellion.

While other characters probably will never appear on TV, it looks like this character will become important at least in the final battle against the White Walkers.

---

Besides that there are too many differences to list them all. Some characters live, while others don't.

As [George R. R. Martin wrote](http://georgerrmartin.com/notablog/2016/01/02/last-year-winds-of-winter/) before season 6:

> Mago, Irri, Rakharo, Xaro Xhoan Daxos, Pyat Pree, Pyp, Grenn, Ser Barristan Selmy, Queen Selyse, Princess Shireen, Princess Myrcella, Mance Rayder, and King Stannis are all dead in the show, alive in the books. Some of them will die in the books as well, yes... but not all of them, and some may die at different times in different ways. Balon Greyjoy, on the flip side, is dead in the books, alive on the show. His brothers Euron Crow's Eye and Victarion have not yet been introduced (will they appear? I ain't saying). Meanwhile Jhiqui, Aggo, Jhogo, Jeyne Poole, Dalla (and her child) and her sister Val, Princess Arianne Martell, Prince Quentyn Martell, Willas Tyrell, Ser Garlan the Gallant, Lord Wyman Manderly, the Shavepate, the Green Grace, Brown Ben Plumm, the Tattered Prince, Pretty Meris, Bloodbeard, Griff and Young Griff, and many more have never been part of the show, yet remain characters in the books.

Comment: OP mentions Aegon in the question, but +1 for the quote.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning this quote was from before season 6 started. At least three or four of these have either been introduced or killed off this season.

Comment: I very much doubt they'll introduce (f)Aegon; his storyline is usurped by Daenerys getting support from the Tyrells and Martell armies. Considering they've done a major clean-up of characters in season six (Euron was only introduced to be the big bad in season seven) and considering that D&D only want to do 15 or so episodes until the end, I don't see them bringing in another surprise Targaryen for no good reason.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Only Targaryens can ride dragons and there are 3 dragons but only two riders yet. I think that's a pretty good reason. Of course they could make something else up. The question can only be answered precisely after the last episode.

Comment: @Chris That rule has not been established in the show. I can easily see them using Tyrion as a dragonrider, avoiding any need to introduce a new character. Or perhaps Euron, who could hijack a dragon via magic.